# Filtering tableau data

Tags: graphql, tableau-api

I want to filter tableau data on bases of Folders . Like I have 3 folders and want data of only one folder . is this possible in tableau ? till now not able to locate api or way to do in graphQL . any lead would be highly appreciated .

Comment: There are options when importing data into Tableau that allow the folder to be specified for groups of data sources. Does that help?

Comment: @matt_black actually I want that data in response of Meta data API. Like first want listing of all folders then want to specify in filter which folder data I want